# Getting the default font size of a multiline TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, font-size

I want to have a font-size preference in percentage relative to the default font-size, so I need to get the default font-size for a TextView.

How do I get the default font-size of a TextView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return the value in pixels within a context:

```
float size = new TextView(this).getTextSize();
```

Comment: That's what I did, but I wonder if there is any other way without creating a new TextView?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findById(R.id.text);
float size = txt.getTextSize();
```

This should do it on an existing one